# Insert values to the new table(role) and assign the privileges to corresponding roles in the database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have 3 tables (role,Privilege, roleid_Privilegeid) and input/output structure as specified below. Received role & privileges in a comma separated format and require to split the role which has to be inserted in role table and the corresponding privileges have to mapped with the role which should be inserted in "roleid_privilegeid" table.

```
Enter the role and the privileges :
Agent,View,Cancel,Process
Shipper,Create,Process,Schedule,Cancel,View
Customer,View,Cancel

Enter the Role :
Agent

Privileges for Agent :
Process
Cancel
View
```

Table structure of role,Privilege, roleid_privilegeid tables:

```
create table privilege
(id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255) not null,primary key(id));

insert into privilege(name) values('Create');
insert into privilege(name) values('Process');
insert into privilege(name) values('Schedule');
insert into privilege(name) values('Cancel');
insert into privilege(name) values('View');

create table role
(id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255) not null,primary key(id));

create table role_privilege
(role_id int not null references role(id),
privilege_id int not null references privilege(id), 
primary key(role_id,privilege_id));
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: I would like to know how to assign the privileges for the corresponding role and it should be inserted in "roleid_privilegeid" table